# Strange characters coming from Arduino when writing to SD card

Tags: arduino, serial-port, sd-card

I am connecting a SD card to an Arduino which is then communicating over serial to Visual studio. Everything works fine independently and 99% collectively. Now if i write this code in the setup in works fine. If i pop it into a function which is called when a specific  character is sent from visual studio I get the strange characters at the bottom.

I have debugged each step of the code and nothing seems abnormal, unfortunately I cannot the code as
1) it's far too long...
2) it's confidential... 
:(

I understand without code I cannot get a complete solution but what are those characters! why in the setup does it work perfectly and in a function I get all kinds of randomness?

```
    myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("test.txt:");

    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}
```

整瑳湩⁧ⰱ㈠‬⸳ࠀ -- Copied straight from the text file

整瑳湩%E2%81%A7ⰱ㈠%E2%80%AC⸳ࠀ -- Output when pasted into google

Comment: Which Arduino?  Are you using `String`, `new`, `malloc`, `realloc` or a library that does?  This smells like memory corruption, which can be caused by many things: dynamic memory, bad pointers or, the eponymic reason you are here, Stack Overflow.  As usual, there is nothing wrong with the snippet

Comment: Its the arduino DUE and yes lots of "String" including 4 x 2D string arrays we are using to upload to a tft screen. I ran into memory issues with the UNO but thought we would be ok with the DUE as its got considerably more ram?

Comment: `整` is probably a unicode character. How do you handle them? (UTF-16 / UTF-8 / not at all ) ?

Comment: @datafiddler Not at all currently. However it seems strange that it works fine during setup but not during the loop. After further testing using a oscilloscope it seems that the arduino will sometime write low to the SD card and transfer the data however the majority of the time it doesn't. Which doesnt explain the strange characters however it could be getting corrupted along the way perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its the arduino DUE and yes lots of "String" including 4 x 2D string arrays we are using to upload to a tft screen. I ran into memory issues with the UNO but thought we would be ok with the DUE as its got considerably more ram?

Well, there's your problem.  I like how you ended that with a question mark.  :)  Having extra RAM is no guarantee that the naughty `String` will behave, NOT EVEN ON SERVERS WITH GIGABYTES OF RAM.  To summarize [my Arduino forum post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=382944.msg2640860#msg2640860):

### Don't use String™

The solutions using C strings (i.e., char arrays) are very efficient.  If you're not sure how to convert a `String` usage to a character array, please post the snippet.  You will get *lots* of help!

`String` will add at least 1600 bytes of FLASH to your program size and 10 bytes per String variable.  Although `String` is fairly easy to use and understand, it will also cause random hangs and crashes as your program runs longer and/or grows in size and complexity.  This is due to [dynamic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)) caused by the heap management routines `malloc` and `free`.

Commentary from systems experts elsewhere on the net:

- [The Evils of Arduino Strings (required reading!)](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/)
- [Why is malloc harmful in embedded systems?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-malloc-harmful-in-embedded-systems)
- [Dr Dobbs Journal](http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/embedded-memory-allocation/240169150)
- [Memory Fragmentation in servers (MSDN)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/02/14/more-on-virtual-memory-memory-fragmentation-and-leaks-and-wow64.aspx)
- [Memory Fragmentation, your worst nightmare (nice graphics)](http://library.softwareverify.com/memory-fragmentation-your-worst-nightmare/)
- [Another answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19295) of mine.